# Information in csv file not retrieved properly using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some contents from this [site](http://www.allconferences.com/search/index/Category__parent_id:1/Venue__country:United%20States/Conference__start_date__from:01-01-2010/sort:start_date/direction:asc/showLastConference:1/page:7/). While writing like the conference head after extracting from the site in `csv` file the first name is not coming properly, e.g. if the word is `microsoft` it is coming as `osoft` but rest all of the words are coming properly

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('random.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    a = csv.writer(csvfile)
    a.writerow(["conferenceHead"])

    url = given above      
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    links = soup.find_all("div")

    r_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"conferenceHead"})
    for item in r_data:
        conferenceHead = item.contents[1].text


        with open('random.csv','a') as csvfile:
            a = csv.writer(csvfile)
            data = [conferenceHead]
        a.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, You have three issues in Your code.

- dual `with open()` statements (on the same file)
- and second open - in append mode, is in a loop, which makes this even worse
- last writerow is out of scope, and csvfile is already closed

This might cause buffer not being written to file, and truncating string You are saving.

After fixing this errors (removing `with open('random.csv','a') as csvfile` and fixing indentation) code runs and output is not trimmed.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('random.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    a = csv.writer(csvfile)
    a.writerow(["conferenceHead"])

    url = "http://www.allconferences.com/search/index"\
          "/Category__parent_id:1/Venue__country:United%20States"\
          "/Conference__start_date__from:01-01-2010/sort:start_date"\
          "/direction:asc/showLastConference:1/page:7/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    links = soup.find_all("div")

    r_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"conferenceHead"})

    for item in r_data:
        conferenceHead = item.contents[1].text
        data = [conferenceHead]
        a.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Is it possible if you can give me your email id and help me with some of the problems.

Comment: @AtulPant I am sorry, this would be rather unwise to post email. But if You want, enter means of contacting You in Your "about me" page, reply to this comment with \@JustMe and I'll contact You.